# Jquery function not executing on form submission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this form:

```
<form id="user-info-form" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-input-wrapper col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input-name" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="input-name" class="form-input" placeholder="Your Name..." required />
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="form-input-wrapper col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input-email-address" class="form-label">Enter your Email address</label>
                <input id="input-email-address" type="email" name="input-email-address" class="form-input" placeholder="Email Address..." required />
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>                                      
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper button-wrapper-second">
        <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

On it's submission I'm trying to execute some code without using what was submitted on the form for now. 
The jquery code:

```
$('#user-info-form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        code to be executed..
    })
```

However, it's just not working. I instead end up getting redirected to the same page with this URL:

```
http://localhost/project/?input-name=nickolas&input-email-address=nickolas%40gmail.com
```

The default browser submission it seems.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also make sure the form exists in the DOM when your JS runs. You may be missing a document.ready event handler

Comment: There appears to be a Typo in your example. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate the issue. I used the following test code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#user-info-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Submitted");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="user-info-form" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-input-wrapper col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-name" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="input-name" class="form-input" placeholder="Your Name..." required />
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input-wrapper col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-email-address" class="form-label">Enter your Email address</label>
        <input id="input-email-address" type="email" name="input-email-address" class="form-input" placeholder="Email Address..." required />
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper button-wrapper-second">
    <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```